# Is there any lyx online editor

Tags: lyx, online

I was wondering if an online LyX editor like Google Docs exists or whether there is a project of online editor under development, either within the LyX community or as an independent project?

Comment: Not exactly the same but there exist certain editors like overleaf which compile frequently and update the compiled view.

Comment: If you're specifically asking about LyX, then I would post a question at a LyX specific forum/mailing list, greater chance of developers seeing it: http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists Other than that, Authorea might be of interest.

Comment: The official ways to collaborate in LyX: https://wiki.lyx.org/Devel/Collaboration

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use LyX online at [rollaps](https://www.rollapp.com/app/lyx). There have been efforts made in the past to allow collaborative (e.g. simultaneous) editing in LyX, but these have not made it far. See e.g. [this](https://wiki.lyx.org/Devel/SummerOfCode2013Ideas#toc10) Google summer of code project.

Comment: that solution uses VNC (or similar lossy image compressions based technique), I thought it's worth mentioning...

Answer (score 2):

There's a fully working LyX chat extension, allowing you to LyX-chat with (XMPP) friends:
 http://wiki.lyx.org/Devel/LyXChat#sDevel.LyXChat_8

There's also a proof-of-concept, badly crashing, extension demonstrating multiple LyX users interactively editing the same document:
 http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7964

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will like [Authorea](https://www.authorea.com) - a collaborative platform to read, write, discuss, and publish research. Write in Markdown, LaTeX, HTML, or plain text. Git-like changes management.