# Is there a web-based editor that supports both rich text and tex?

Tags: editors

Is there a web-based editor that supports both rich text and tex? In one side of the editor, I can edit and format text, images as if I do with MS office word, on the other side of it, tex is generated automatically and simultaneous.

Comment: Overleaf is the closest to what you're describing.

Comment: Closely related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330934/is-there-any-lyx-online-editor. The answers mention LyX online options and as an alternative Authorea, both WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: Overleaf doesn't show rich text and TeX code next to each other, but you can switch between the two (the left pane is the sources, either as rich text or TeX code, the right pane the generated PDF).